# Mirror viewmodel for Source engine, ends up horribly deformed?

Tags: modeling, animation, mirror

I don't know if it's a problem with Blender or Source, but I need to flip a viewmodel in Counter-Strike (it's lefthanded in game, I want it to be right handed), but when I flip the model (by scaling by -1) and export the reference and animation files, it ends up horribly deformed in CS, but it looks fine in Blender. Also, when I export in Blender I get the error *"Warning: Armature has non-uniform scale. Mesh deformation in Source will differ from blender"* Is there another way to mirror a viewmodel, am I doing something wrong, or is this a source problem?

Blender:
[image]

Ingame:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to keep with the expectations of the Source Engine while in Blender (I do Dota2 workshop stuff, I should know), so this is some stuff that you should check from my similar struggles:

- Do the animations play right? Do they look right in blender?
- What does the source model viewer show?
- Is the scale, location, and rotation applied (correctly)?
- Did you consider that Source is sensitive to bone labels?

  - Example:  If you simply mirrored the model and animations, Source will still attempt to align bone labeled "right" to the right hand side for IK purposes, and vice-versa for the left hand side.
  - If your model looks wrong in the Source Model Viewer, try creating a custom, unused animation.  If that imports correctly, your animations are mirrored incorrectly.
- Are you able to export the model/animations and directly re-import them successfully without modifications?

  - Failure to do so suggests something wrong with your tooling or process.

Without more to go on, I can only provide these generic troubleshooting tips.

Comment: Animations play fine, yes. HLMV shows the same as in-game does. Scale/rotation is applie correctly from what I know, yes. Yes, that's why I'm doing it. (ingame left handed is set to right hand and vice versa, I'm doing this to fix it), and I don't understand exactly what you mean by the second point. So I this time only changed the animations and not the reference files and it works but instead of flipping it on the X axis like in blender it flips it on both the Z and Y axis, however flipping the Z axis in blender does nothing (it stays the same).

Comment: Flipping the Y axis in blender also flips both the Y and Z axis in source. And to answer the last question, it imports as how it looks in source, not blender (Z and Y axis flipped in blender instead of just being flipped on Y axis when exporting)